# How to Revert Back Previous Custom Media Storage Link on WordPress via Filezilla

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Actually the previous developer use custom media storage for the wordpress 
 storage media by that we not able to add new media because it display error at the time of upload directory not created check its parent have the write access .. that type of error it shows. So to avoid that error we change the custom media storage link to default one: which is now.. wp-content/uploads
After that site is running fine but when I saw some images are showing thumbnail problem then after sometime site is down and it showing only error message.

Only way I have where I make it work again is by using Filezilla.

I had also make a backup of it. Which I restore after by using only the wp-config file. By that site is running again but As I said if I visit another of it pages which are basically full of products images then again site will down. 
I tried so many things by adding code lines in wp-config file to add that custom link again which previous developer was use but all in vain.
I had update the link by login to the wordpress media settings. But now it not shows any area to add custom link anywhere.

define('UPLOADS',".'media');

I have also try that line of code by creating a folder in Wordpress with 'Media' and add all the media files into this but is also not work for me. 
And Originally my media files path is /public-html/wp-content/uploads

I just want to resolve it by previously customized adding link option and also want to enable the permission to add new media without disturbing the already publish images and other media on the running wordpress site.

Comment: did the previous developer use /year/month/ structure and you simply copied all from /media to /uploads?
i would say, you, edit directly the the database.
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` where post_type='attachment'

Answer (score 0):

did the previous developer use /year/month/ structure and you simply copied everything from /media to /uploads?
i would say, edit directly the database. first, checkout the links in the field GUID
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` where post_type='attachment'

the links are in the GUID field. Now take a database search and [replace tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) and replace the wrong paths on the whole db:

eg:
https://example.com/media  with  https://example.com/wp-content/uploads
and escaped
https://example.com/media  with  https://example.com/wp-content/uploads
and just to make sure, also replace the url-encoded versions (get it with [this tool](https://www.url-encode-decode.com/))

this should fix all permalinks as well as the links in the post-contents.

Comment: He use that structure before. ( /var/sites/b/exampleurl.com/public_html/wp-content/uploads )

Comment: And I don't have its cpanel access which is why I can't handle its database also.

Comment: I only have the filezilla access by where I can revert it back. I also have the Wordpress login access but as i said after changing its media storage default address it did not show any option where I can modify that link and use the previous one again.

Comment: filezilla access is fine. you can upload the replace tool and install the Adminer plugin to examin the database.